# htacces - need to fix broken links coming from other sites to mine

Tags: .htaccess

I am having an issue where Google Webmaster Tools is reporting a ton of 404 links to my site which are coming from ask.com.

I have tried to get ask.com to fix their side but of course they are not, so now I am stuck with over 11k of bad links to my site which I am suspecting is effecting my ranks right now.

Anyways I have a possible way to 301 them, but not sure how to do it with `.htaccess`.

Here is the bad link pointing to my site

```
http://www.freescrabbledictionary.com/sentence-examples/fere-film/feverous/about.php
```

It should be

```
http://www.freescrabbledictionary.com/sentence-examples/fere-film/feverous/
```

Besides the `about.php` there are other variations of endings as well, I basically need to be able to remove the ending.

Problem is that the URL after `/sentence-examples/` can change. The beginning is always:

```
http://www.freescrabbledictionary.com/sentence-examples/
```

So basically:

```
http://www.freescrabbledictionary.com/sentence-examples/<-keep but can change->/<-keep but can change->/<-remove this->
```

Comment: You’ll have to specify your `<-remove this->` more strict. Should it be anything of the form filename-dot-ending? If so, what if one of your `<-keep but can change->` would match that pattern as well? (Or are they guaranteed to always end with a slash?) And of course: What have you tried so far?

Comment: yup it does thanks for clearing that up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `.htaccess` should be placed on the folder before `sentence-examples`:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect /sentence-examples/anything/anything/remove to /sentence-examples/anything/anything/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(sentence-examples/[^/]+/[^/]+)/.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R=302,PT,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ /sentence-examples/examplesentence.php?havethis=$1&word=$2 [L]
```

Change `302` to `301` once you confirm it's working as expected.

If you have a CMS installed you might need a different rule to work along with it without conflicting.

**Keep in mind that if you had previously tried different redirects using `301` aka permanent redirect its recommended that you use a different browser to test this rule to avoid the caching.**

Comment: Tried your example, but nothing seem to happen. Don't I need to use a RediectMatch?

Comment: No CMS and yes I have way more in my htaccess file

Comment: Check out http://www.freescrabbledictionary.com/htaccess.txt I made it a text file for you to look at

Comment: Nothing happened different

Comment: I made the change and still nothing. Also I updated my htaccess.txt file so you can see the changes I made. I didnt make the exact same change as you because I need to make sure that m.freescrabbledictionary.com redirects to www.freescrabbledictionary.com/m/. I dont want all m. traffic to simple redirect to www. I do want freescrabbledictionary.com to redirect to www.freescrabbledictionary.com

Comment: When I go to that link I just get a 404

Comment: Ok Just remember that I have an additional htaccess file in the folder sentence-examples Here is the link to that file http://www.freescrabbledictionary.com/htaccess2.txt

Comment: are you talking just about the top part of your answer that you are editing?

Comment: @CesarBielich Yes just the top, and if you have an .htaccess inside the sentence folder then anything you put on the root .htaccess wont work because the .htaccess on that folder overwrites it ... you should have said that early ...

Comment: so should I just put that one line in the other htaccess file? Sorry about that man I totally forgot about it

Comment: ok the redirect seems to be working now, but now the page is blank. w00t we are getting somewere :) http://www.freescrabbledictionary.com/sentence-examples/heli-hero/hemihedral/

Comment: I just tried flipping the rules as well in the htaccess file and still blanks out the page

Comment: almost there. Now it does show the correct page and word but the url still shows the *.php at the end. So the redirect is not happening. Check out this url http://www.freescrabbledictionary.com/sentence-examples/heli-hero/hemihedral/contact.php

Comment: Thanks so so much for all this help FYI, you rock :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37840/discussion-between-cesar-bielich-and-prix)

Comment: @CesarBielich yes, I don't know what your proxy is doing but the 302 should have worked, thinking about some alternative but for the time being at least the page shows properly now and you can use the cannonical tag on the HTML to define the true URL so google doesn't think of it as a duplicate.

Comment: @CesarBielich give it another try on the update and if that doesn't work change this part `[R=302,PT,L]` to `[R=302,P,L]` and try again.

Comment: Didnt work, but I did fix my canonical for the pages so they always point to the right page. I think at this point that is what I have to deal with. Thanks so much for everything man

Comment: Just realized I found an issue with this fix, it has cause the previous directory to 404. Go to http://www.freescrabbledictionary.com/sentence-examples/cowh-crep/ as an example. it 404's

Comment: I reverted to using canonical to fix the issue temporarily till I can get this figured out

Comment: @CesarBielich What was the rule I gave u? that is easy to fix, just need to make the last group optional. Since I've edited the answer since then I don't have it anymore so if you still have it will save me time.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly quick and dirty but I've done a simple test on localhost and [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) just to make sure it works.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sentence-examples/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)\.php http://www.freescrabbledictionary.com/sentence-examples/$1/$2/ [R=301,L]
```

You can see that I've added wildcard groups (.*) to the RewriteRule so that we can pick up the elements of the URL that we need to aid in proper redirection i.e. $1 and $2. You can also use the third one ($3) to get which destinations are being targeted alot for your SEO needs.

**NB:** The rule above assumes that that the redirected URL will always be from a *.php* target and to ensure that you can redirect regardless of whatever comes after the 3rd URL segment replace the RewriteRule with this

```
RewriteRule ^sentence-examples/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ http://www.freescrabbledictionary.com/sentence-examples/$1/$2/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I tried both examples and nothing seems to happen. I tested this as well on htaccess.madewithlove.be and the output it correct. Keep in mind these are links coming from other site to mine. Will this actually redirect the user when they get to a link like this?

Comment: Regardless of where the user is being sent from , the RewriteRule will redirect the user to the specified destination successfully. I have set up a small environment to troubleshoot why the rules provided by @Prix and myself don't seem to work on your server [link](http://lab.briankinyua.com/SO/sentence-examples/fere-film/feverous/about.php). I thought possible it might be because you have another htaccess file under the sentence-examples folder and so far that is not the case.

Comment: @CesarBielich is it possible for you to provide a copy of the access and error logs of the server? I think it can help shed more light on what exactly is happening during the request.